# Chromium based browsers doesn't load local svg

Tags: html, google-chrome, svg, chromium

What i'm trying to achieve is simple load **local** svg image stored in the same directory with index.html as img element source just like following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   <title>Svg Test</title>
</head>
<body>
   <img src="1.svg"/>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that on some windows 7 machines it didn't load at all, throwing:

> Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/xml: "file:///N:/svgTest/1.svg".

I also tried to create img element dynamically using javascript:

```
var imgObj = new Image();
imgObj.onload = function(){
    document.body.appendChild(imgObj);
}
imgObj.src = '1.svg';
```

But this one doesn't work too.
If then i open the same page from any remote server - svg will succesfully load on that problem machine. It would also load locally using firefox or even ie 11.

Answer (score 0):

Set `Content Type` parameter of `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.svg` key to `image/svg+xml`